# What's the use of double boolean variables?

Tags: php, json, boolean, boolean-logic

I am looking at a JSON dataset from an API and I see stuff like this:

```
   "lights_on":1,
   "lights_off":0,
   "doors_locked":0,
   "doors_unlocked":1,
   "sensors_tripped":0,
   "sensors_not_tripped":1
```

Is it just me, or is it kinda silly to have a variable for both states of a boolean? in this example, wouldn't it make more sense to check the value of  `lights_on` and if `0` it must be `false`, if `1` it must be `true`

What is the advantage of the above JSON data set with variables for both the `true` and `false` states and should I be using this in my programs?

Comment: It is a redundancy indeed. Also often it makes sense to use nouns and states. "light: on", "light: bright", "door: locked", "door: ajar". If states are boolean (and always be boolean), then it's also fine.

Comment: code by Schrödinger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is merely emulating real-world conditions where you want both a 'true' and a 'false' variable to respond. Their default values is for both to be 'false', which means no decision was made. If both were set to 'true', then an irrational decision has been made. This is a way to make sure the software is working correctly.
Oddly enough the same scenario applies to remote contact switch's for 'door open', or 'door closed'. By having both states returned for software analysis the users know that the wires are not shorted, which could cause both an open and closed status (illogical), and both wires are not false, which normally means the cable has been cut or the sensor is bad.
It is the simplest form of self-checking to make sure the source of a software or hardware status report is valid.
 This would be implicitly used where a block of code is reading real-world Boolean inputs, and the next block of code would read both the 'true' and 'false' flags to make sure there is a valid answer. Also in real-world conditions a digital filter would be used to make sure the answer stays the same for something like 1/10th of a second, depending on how fast the software must respond to a change.
Then more downstream code would take action by issuing a status report, sound an alarm, updating a log, or any number of functions deemed important.
I have built these multi-stage threads in several of my ATE units for testing products.
Real-world inputs can be noisy and software created Boolean can have errors, so *any* ambiguities *MUST* be filtered out before the end-point software takes real-world action.

Comment: So it's particularly good for interfacing with real world devices, would you bother to do this in a purely programmatic environment?

Comment: @Black_Stormy. Please see my addition to my answer.